# Twig множество параметров

Tags: php, twig

Господа
вопрос по Twig

```
     $data = $this->newsRepo->getAll();

    $isAdmin = $this->session->isAdmin(Request::getData('login'));

    View::renderTemplate('Home/index.html', ['data' => $data, 'rbac' => $isAdmin]);
```

> 'Unexpected token "operator" of value "=" in "Home/index.html" at line
>   34'

```
 {% for news in data %}
    <h2>
        <a href="/news/view/{{ news.id }}">{{ news.title }}</a>
    </h2>

    {% if rbac !== false %}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/news/editPage/{{ news.id }}">Редактировать <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/news/delete/{{ news.id }}">Удалить <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    <hr>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

34 строка это соответственно

```
{% if rbac !== false %}
```

В чем я не прав?

Comment: https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#logic `!==` => `!=` || `!==` => `is not`

Answer (score 0):

Замените !== на !=, в twig’е нет такого оператора, как !==, это не php.